# How to use global send keys in excel in blueprism

Tags: excel, blueprism

I have material copied to the clipboard which is basically unstructured and structured text from an application page. Now, I have some prefefined string manipulation formulas written in an excel. I want to paste the text by using Ctrl + v on A1 cell in excel. The complete text does not need to be put in A1, but when Ctrl + V is pressed, it separates into different rows and becomes usable for my purpose.

I am unable to used Global Send  Keys with excel as it needs an element as input. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: There are no elements for Excel because Blue Prism's default `MS Excel VBO` is designed to use the faster VBA back-end as opposed to modelling the interface. Why not just use the pre-existing `Paste` action in the MS Excel VBO?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an `Application Modeller` for excel application to launch the application or you can attach the process to already opened Excel application.
2. Once the process got attached to blue prism, and `Application Modeller` is created, you can send `Global send key event` by using the root node from `Application Modeller`.
3. To send `Global send key event`, use the `Navigate Stage` of blue prism, drag the root node element, and select the `Global send key event` action from drop down under action column.
4. Input for Ctrl + V in `Global send key event` would be `<{CTRL}V>{CTRL}`

**NOTE**: The application must be attached and activated before sending `Global send key event`